# CMTimeClampToRange() doesn't seem to return a CMTime that's inside the given range

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cmtime

I have the following code in my project:

```
CMTimeRange clipRange = clip.range;
CMTime clipTime = CMTimeClampToRange(editor.currentClipTime, clipRange);
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTimeRange/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMTimeClampToRange), `CMTimeClampToRange()` should behave like:

> For a given `CMTime` and `CMTimeRange`, returns the nearest `CMTime` inside that time range.

However, when I add this:

```
assert(CMTimeRangeContainsTime(clipRange, clipTime));
```

The assertion fails. The documentation for `CMTimeRangeContainsTime()` states:

> Indicates whether a time is contained within a time range.

I would assume that *inside* and *within* mean the same, but apparently it doesn't; is there an elegant way to clamp a `CMTime` in a range so that it satisfies `CMTimeRangeContainsTime()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the following hack:

```
clipTime = CMTimeMaximum(clipRange.start, CMTimeSubtract(clipTime, CMTimeMake(1, clipTime.timescale)));
```

Basically, it subtracts the smallest non-empty timespan within the same timescale from the clamped time and makes sure we don't yield a negative value.